# Where date time is?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have Mysql filed `date` with `datetime` format.

How can I do `where` request comparing only date without time part?

I mean the following:

```
date = 2016-04-45 11:00:00
```

When I do request I should get row above:

```
where("date", "=", "2016-04-45")
```

Comment: use `DATE(your_datetime_column)` to extract the date part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$q->where(DB::raw("DATE(created_at) = '".date('Y-m-d')."'"));
$q->whereDate('created_at', '=', date('Y-m-d'));
```

with Carbon

```
$q->whereDate('created_at', '=', Carbon::today()->toDateString());

$q->whereDay('created_at', '=', date('d'));
$q->whereMonth('created_at', '=', date('m'));
$q->whereYear('created_at', '=', date('Y'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
whereRaw('date(created_at) = ?', [Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d')] )
```